# Github change repository makefile to CPP

Tags: github

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Gj8L.jpg)

How to rename makefile to CPP

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this image shows, but if it's info about language which is used in repo then you should just use more .cpp files, as it's created automatically ;)